# PDF to HTML conversion for web site

Tags: html, pdf

I am looking or a (preferably free) dll that can be used on a web site to convert pdf documents to html in a .Net IIS environment.  It would be nice if it could accept the pdf as a byte array or file stream, and output the html as a stream suitable for Response.Write.  It would really be great if the output HTML retained form inputs.

Has anyone seen such an animal?

Answer (score 1):

Just bear in mind HTML does not have all the features of PDF so it may not look as good in HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [Aspose.PDF fo r.NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) 
It's not cheap, but their products are great and the documentation and user forums are amazing. Can't say enough good things about the product. IF you do a lot of .PDF manipulation, the price isn't bad for what you get.